# part of speech tagging using taggedCorpusReader

Tags: python

I have a big problem distorting my proceeding. I have my own corpus already tagged (word/tag), but Im finding it difficult to import simplify from nltk.tag ,the error keeps saying " cannot import name simplify".

Comment: Please provide your full error traceback and the relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: ok , let me bring it down to this .  Is there any module named 'simplify' in python 2.7. If yes ,then how can i get it/download it ,